# Error msg when updating from Anaconda Launcher

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

After I get prompted to update applications (ipython, glueviz) in the Anaconda Launcher window, and I proceed with the update (click button next to launch), I get this msg:

```
Unable to remove files for package: pyyaml
Please close all processes running code from pyyaml and try again
```

Looking online I fount [this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/conda/Okh2K9d2wHY), I followed the instruction to perform:

```
conda update -f conda
```

But now when I start the Anaconda Launcher it doesn't populate the apps.

Thanks

Windows 7. Python 2.7.8-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Anaconda Launcher issue is a bug that will be fixed by a bug release of conda later today (3.15.1).